# best practice renaming ssh login server

Tags: ssh, migration, best-practices

quick question:

let's say you have a ssh login computer called `sshlogin.example.com`. Now for some obscure reason, your company decided to rename that machine to `ssh.example.com`. 
What's the best practice here? should I generate new ssh keys for that machine? Alternatively, should I just keep the old ssh keys?

**EDIT1:** one could imagine that whoever decided to rename the machine in the first place, might change his / her mind. so `ssh.example.com` might become `sshlogin.example.com` after a while again. Maybe this should be considered?

**EDIT2:** what if the IP address would change? what's the suggested procedure?

Comment: If the IP address changes, clients will perceive it as a new host. This will cause problems with the stored keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about what best practice is, but I'd be tempted to keep the old SSH keys. It's the same service, actually on the same machine, and will probably have the same IP. To me, the "rename" isn't changing anything sufficiently to justify a new set of keys.